# Why is River Song surprised the ship is heading for Darillium?

Tags: doctor-who, river-song

In the 2015 Christmas special *The Husbands of River Song*, River Song says she dug up the ship to find out when it crashed:

> SCRATCH: What meteor strike?
>   COMPUTER: Alert. Meteor storm imminent.
>   RIVER: That meteor strike.
>   FLEMMING: How could you know?
>   RIVER: I'm an archaeologist from the future. I dug you up.
>   (Boom! Shudder.)
>   RIVER: See you in four hundred years.

Then why is she surprised? When it is about to crash into Darillium, surely she had to go there to dig them up, and would have known that's where they where headed? Yes, it might be a surprise she's headed there with the Doctor, but she should know that's where it's headed.

Comment: How do you know she *was* surprised? (Transcript is [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-13.html) for easy reference.)

Comment: She didn't LITERALLY dig them up. It could have been a way to say she made research about the crash, you know, with books, newspapers, stuff like that. At least that's what I think, that's why I don't post it as an answer.

Comment: @tilley31: I agree with you, and I think there's support in the episode: River mentions something about having a book about the subject.

Comment: @randal'thor: thanks for the link to the transcript, it helped fill in the holes in the sieve otherwise known as my memory. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's explained by River's next line after the part you quoted:

> RIVER: I had this book. History's Finest Exploding Restaurants. The best food for free. Skip the coffee.

She dug up the ship Hermione-style, not with a shovel. She had no idea, and didn't particularly care about, where the debris landed, because she didn't plan to still be around when said debris landed - that's why she stole the Tardis, after all.

Comment: Hermione who???

Comment: @Randal'Thor: why, everyone's favorite bookworm, that's who. :)

Comment: *I* know who you mean, but I also think this answer should be comprehensible to people who watch DW but know nothing about HP :-)